# HTML Regex for multiple phone numbers matching not working

Tags: html, regex, validation

I need to validate two types of phone number formats with in one input.
The patterns are,

+XX XXX XX XX XX or

+XX X XXX XX XX

so I use the following pattern

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="input" pattern="^\+\d{2} \d{1,3} \d{2,3} \d{2} \d{2}$" required />
```

but it validates some other patterns like +xx xx xx xx xx

I need to know how to use HTML RegEx exactly for the above mentioned patterns. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` for or operation

This will work

```
^\+\d{2} (\d{1} \d{3}|\d{3} \d{2}) \d{2} \d{2}$
```

Comment: Yes this works as expected. Thanks for your hand :))

Answer (score 1):

You need to make [:space:] visible to regexp

```
^\+\d{2}\ (\d{1,3}\ )+(\d{2}\ ?)$
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this does not works as expected.